# Ruby rest client gem and Github API

Tags: ruby, github-api, rest-client

To query the Github API with 'rest_client' I do the following, if I want to search for users in London:

```
require 'rest_client'
response = RestClient.get 'https://api.github.com/search/users', {:params => {:q => 'location:london'}}
```

Direct browser query:

> [https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:london](https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3alondon)

How would I construct the query if for example, I wanted to **match users that joined at or after May 11th, 2013?**

Reference: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users#created

If I were to directly input this query using a browser I would do

> [https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:london%20created:2013-03-06](https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3alondon%20created:2013-03-06)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your search query for the browser

> [https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3alondon+created:>2013-03-16](https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3alondon%20created%3a%3E2013-03-16)

You can ask `rest client` to do the same like that:

```
params = {:q => 'location:london created:>2013-03-16'}
result = RestClient.get('https://api.github.com/search/users', {:params => params})
```

Checking the equality of results can be a tricky task. One way here is to compare `total_count` of objects using json parser:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(result)['total_count'] # => 4552, just as stated if opened in browser
```

Comment: Looking at the answer I can't believe I struggled with this for such a long time. Thanks